# How to store Javascript array elements in excel file while converting JSON object to excel file in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, xlsx

I've a usecase where I need to export user data into excel file. User model(mongo db model) consists a field of type `array`. While exporting, every field is stored into excel file except, that array field data. How to store that array data into excel file as comma separated values?

Here's my code:

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');

exportCustomerDataToExcel: async function(customerId){
    let err,customerData;

    [err, customerData]=await to(Customer.find({"_id":customerId},'name email phone unit block communityAccountNo status').lean().exec());

    //*name email phone unit block communityAccountNo status* are fields of customer & unit is an array

    if(err) {TE(err, true)};

    if(!customerData || customerData.length==0) return false;

    if(customerData){
        customerData.map(function(elem) {
            if (elem._id) delete elem._id

        });
        var newWB=XLSX.utils.book_new();
        var newWS=XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(customerData);
        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(newWB, newWS,"Customers");
        [err,excelWB]=await to(this.writeFileQ(newWB, "./public/exports/"+customerId+".xlsx"));
        if(err) TE(err, true);
        return ({file:customerId+".xlsx"});
    }
},

writeFileQ: function(workbook, filename) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        XLSX.writeFileAsync(filename, workbook, (error, result) => {
          (error)? reject(error) : resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Sample code is:

```
{
    "name" : "Some Name",
    "email" : "SomeName@gmail.com",
    "phone" : "94XXXXXXXX",
    "communityAccountNo" : "ABCD1234",
    "status" : true,
    "block" : "1",
    "unit" : [ 
        "9-2", 
        "9-3"
    ]
}
```

Here is the excel I got:

[image]

I want to store the unit elements as, **9-2,9-3** under the **unit** tab. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reformat the array in a string before creating the excel file to make it works the way you want. You can achieve this by using the Array `join` method, and use `,` as parameter. Something like this:

```
customerData.unit = customerData.unit.join(',');
```

Or even `customerData.unit = customerData.unit.join();` since `,` is the default parameter.

And then create your excel sheet.

Comment: And do you know how to store them as array in database when I tried to update the excel file and import? For ex, I'd update the unit and upload, it would store as an array in database. Is it possible?

Comment: It depends of the database, if you are using MongoDB, you won't have any problem pushing an array in a collection. If you are using MySQL, it's not that efficient. But you can use JSON SQL types to store arrays